# Mocking attribute of a file in python fails

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying to mock a function call inside file

here is the file dummy.py

```
from core.connection_util import create_graphql_client

config = settings.ABCD
gql = create_graphql_client(config)
print("debug", gql) # this print statemet is not coming either.

def get_instance():
return gql
```

unit test file test_dummy.py

```
def test_get_instance():
with patch('dummy.adapter.create_graphql_client') as mocked_create_graphql_client:
\# Configure the mock's behavior
mocked_gql = 'Mocked GraphQL Client'
mocked_create_graphql_client.return_value = mocked_gql

        # Call the function under test
        instance = get_instance()
    
        # Assertions
        assert instance == mocked_gql
        mocked_create_graphql_client.assert_called_once_with(settings.ABCD)
```

I tried with mocker fixture too still no luck. Any help would be appriciated thanks.

I am running things in pycharm community edition and I tried running the test via terminal as well no luck.

Comment: what is the error ? also why do you "adapter" in the patch ?